# simple random walk and stopping time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

Suppose $S_n:= \sum^n_{i}X_i$ be asymmetric simple random walk. with $P(X_{1}=+1)=p>1/2$, $P(X_{1}=-1)=q$, $p+q=1$, and $S_{0}=0$. Define $T_1 := \inf\{n: S_n = 1\}$. And we know that for $\theta > 0$, $e^{\theta}E\varphi(\theta)^{-T_1}=1$, where $$\varphi(\theta)= pe^{\theta} +qe^{-\theta}.$$

$\textbf{Question}$: Find the probability $$P(T_1=2k+1), k\ge 0.$$

I am really stuck on this question, could you please give me some details about how to solve this question? Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Hint: Express $e^\theta$ as a function of $\varphi(\theta)$.

Comment: Hi @Did, could you provide more details about that? Thank you!

Comment: Sure - but first, what did you try to apply this hint? Please be specific, or one could be led to believe you did nothing and are just waiting for a full answer to pop up.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_{x} = \inf\{n \geq 0 : S_{n} = x\}$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now you can show that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(T_{y} = n | S_{0}=x) = \mathbb{P}(T_{y-x} = n | S_0 = 0),\qquad n \in \mathbb{N}.
\end{equation}
So we can assume without loss of generality that $S_{0} = 0$. Now define the interarrival times $\xi_{n} := T_{n} - T_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 1$.

It can be shown that the sequence $\{\xi_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is i.i.d.

Because of this you can compute the probability generating function of $T_{x}$ and $T_{-x}$ if you can determine the probability generating function of $T_{1}$ and $T_{-1}$, respectively since for $\varphi(s) = \mathbb{E}(s^{T_{1}} | S_{0} = 0)$ we get
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(s^{T_{x}} | S_{0} = 0) = (\varphi(s))^{x}.
\end{equation}

Now with first step analysis we get

\begin{equation}
\varphi(s) = \mathbb{E}(s^{T_{1}} | S_{0} = 0) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4pqs^{2}}}{2qs}.
\end{equation}
Similarly
\begin{equation}
\psi(s) = \mathbb{E}(s^{T_{-1}} | S_{0} = 0) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4pqs^{2}}}{2ps}.
\end{equation}
So for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ we get
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}(s^{T_{x}}|S_{0} = 0)=
  \begin{cases}
    \left(\varphi(s)\right)^{x}, & \mbox{if $x > 0$ } \\
    \left(\psi(s)\right)^{|x|}, & \mbox{if $x < 0$}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Now $\varphi^{(2k+1)}(0) = (2k+1)! \cdot \mathbb{P}(T_{1} = 2k + 1)$

Comment: Since you're new here, let me give you a rough idea about deletion on this site.  I appreciate your effort to this [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9473/psq-and-the-faq), but questions not meeting the standards of this site are often [victims of deletion "by the votes of people"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28168/290189), in particular, by some users in the chatroom [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude).

Comment: Hi @wayne, I am sorry, but what's the meaning of $\varphi(s)^{(2k+1)}(0)$ and how do you get the last equality? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you are a second year PHD student in pure mathematics, you have to know what are the meaning of $\varphi^{(2k+1)}(0)$